# useCallback hook returns older version of state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this `useCallback` hook that updates a state based on some filtering.

```
const onAcccountChange = useCallback(
    (e: React.ChangeEvent < HTMLInputElement > ) => {
        if (dataBaseStored.account === getValue('account')) {
            onChange(e, {
                target: {
                    name: 'password',
                    validation: ''
                }
            });
        } else {
            onChange(e, {
                target: {
                    name: 'password',
                    validation: 'required',
                    value: '•••••'
                }
            });
        }
    },
    [onChange, getValue]
);
```

My app has an Input field for updating account name.

```
<Input
 label={'account'}
 name="account"
 value={getValue('account')}
 onChange={onAccessKeyHandle}
/>
```

In this case, if the account name stored in the database and the account name on the UI correspond, set the validation for password field on `''`, otherwise set it to `required` (internal validation that checks whether the input field has a value or not). However, `getValue('account')` returns me one value behind the original. For example, if the database stored account is `new_account` and I type `new_account1`, on `console.log(getValue('account'))` I'll get `new_account` and the filter will hit the first, of `if/else`, part. I'm well aware that `setState` is an async method and that's the reason for getting this value. Logging the value in a `useEffect()` is correct while in `useCallback` is not so my filtering isn't valid.

`onChange` is a function that just does `setState` and has two parameters (the second one is optional to update 2 states at once) while the `getValue()` is a function that returns me the state based on a name.

Is there a way to obtain the latest value of the state inside `useCallback`? How can I make my filtering work and shift the validation accordingly by the  filter?

Answer (score 1):

I'd move `getValue('account')` into a variable and add it as a dependency to your `useCallback`, instead of `getValue`, like:

```
const account = getValue('account');

const onAcccountChange = useCallback(
    (e: React.ChangeEvent < HTMLInputElement > ) => {
        if (dataBaseStored.account === account) {
            onChange(e, {
                target: {
                    name: 'password',
                    validation: ''
                }
            });
        } else {
            onChange(e, {
                target: {
                    name: 'password',
                    validation: 'required',
                    value: '•••••'
                }
            });
        }
    },
    [onChange, account]
);

return <Input
 label={'account'}
 name="account"
 value={account}
 onChange={onAccessKeyHandle}
/>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! However, I still get the old value :/

Comment: also maybe it makes sense to add `dataBaseStored.account` as a dependency too

Comment: I added it, still same. I tried to `console.log(account)` before this `useCallback` and it logs the correct value. Inside the hook, I still get one value behind. Oddly weird. @Georgy

Comment: I did manage to solve it. Instead of filtering by `account`, I filtered `if database_record === e.target.value` and it works. @Georgy

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `onChange` and `getValue` as dependencies, use the state itself.

Comment: I tried this as well but it didn't work sadly. Thanks for the answer tho :)

Comment: How do you set the state, can you add the two functions? Do you create a new object?